# Height and width of a graph made by one/two element subsets of {1,2,...,n}

Tags: combinatorics

I have this question (seemingly simple, though there is something I don't understand). 
Consider the set $S=\{1,2,...,n\}$ and construct the set $P$ of one element or two element subsets of S. (I understand this as meaning $\{1\},\{1,2\}$ belong to S, etc.). Partially order P by set inclusion: $a\leq b\Leftrightarrow a\subseteq b$

My question has three parts:
a) Find the height of P, $h(P)$.

b) Find the width of P, $w(P)$.

c) How many chains of P have $h(P)$ elements?

For a), I know that h(P) is the maximum length of a chain in P. A chain C is a set {a,b,...,c} such that any two elements of C are comparable. 
So, we have to find the maximum length of a set $\{a,b,...,c\}\subseteq P(S)$=the powerset of S, such that $a\leq b\leq ...\leq c$ (I write $\leq$ for set inclusion). So, a maximal chain would be $C=\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$ and so $h(P)=2$. 
Is this correct?

For b), I know that $w(P)$ is the maximum length of an antichain in P, that is of a set where any two elements are not comparable. So we need construct an antichain that is maximal. I was thinking of {1},{2},....,{n}. This is an antichain and maximal, correct?

For c) I don't quite understand what I am supposed to prove. Any help welcome...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you write `{1},{2},....,{n}`, the curly braces disappear. You need to put a `\ ` in front of each one: `\{1\},\{2\},\dots,\{n\}` gives $\{1\},\{2\},\dots,\{n\}$ (`\dots` looks better than `...`). Also, that antichain is maximal, but it's far from the greatest, generally.

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks... Any hints on the problem?

Comment: None of the two-element sets contain one another, and usually there are more of those than there are one-element sets (for $n=1,2$ there are more one-element sets, and for $n=3$, there are equally many, but for $n\geq 4$, you want to count the two-element sets for the width).

Comment: Cryptic... But understood. You mean for c), we have the chains {{1},{1,2}}, {{1},{1,3}},..,{{n},{1,n}}, {{2},{1,{2}}},... etc?

Comment: It was meant for (b), not (c), but sure. Yes, those are the chains in (c) that you need to count.

Comment: Oh I see. The antichains are n choose 2... Thanks!